# Heroku not displaying all pug views

Tags: node.js, heroku, pug

I'm making a website, I'm using node and express on the back end, pug on the frontend.

My website is split up into few views via pug.

Layout, I have as the highest view, all of the views "inherits" from there.

So layout ends with

`block content`

and everything after that starts with:

```
   extends layout

     block content

       and then rest of the pug code for that view.
```

I have one view, that is `map` which inherits from `layout` but then also has children on it's own.

So the hierarchy is 
`layout`  --> `map` --> `content`

Locally I have no problem rendering as follows:

`router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('content');
});`

and having the map displaying as well.

When uploading on Heroku however, heroku displays `content` AND `layout`but not the map!

Even if `content` starts with

`extends map`

`block content`

Does anyone know why heroku does that?

Answer (score 0):

try renaming the content of the map page as mapcontent or similar.